# Gradient of summation involving max function

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, machine-learning

I'm having trouble figuring out how to start taking the gradient with respect to w ($\frac{\partial J(w)}{dw}$) of the following function:

$$J(w) = \sum_{i=1}^{M} max[0, -w^Tx_iy_i]$$
where $w \in \mathbb{R}^n, x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ and $y_i \in \{-1,1\}$. Assume $w^Tx_i \neq 0, \forall i$

If the function was simply:
$$J(w) = \sum_{i=1}^{M}-w^Tx_iy_i$$
then the answer would just be: $\sum_{i=1}^{M}-x_iy_i$ right? But surely this isn't how you would solve the first question correct?

Comment: You'll have to check the value of above objective function for every sample, and take derivative in the manner of the second equation. In order to update, make use of the non-zero gradients.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Shikhar. Unfortunately there aren't any samples. This is just a general question without a particular data set.